# Sort categorical data in custom order

Tags: sorting, powerbi

In PowerBI I have the categorical values 'Small', 'Medium' and 'Large' and I have these on my x-axis. I want them to be in the order above but they appear sorted alphabetically. Can I define an order for categoricals (as I can in R using factors)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [Sort by column](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-sort-by-column/) feature.